# An error occurred while finding the resource dictionary (MahApps 2.4.7) (WPF)

Tags: .net, wpf, mahapps.metro

Im using the of MahApps for .net 4 Client Profile. then I change the Target framework from .net 4 client profile to .Net Framework 4.6 and reinstall the latest version of MahApps (MahApps 2.4.7).
Then I encountered this error.

**An error occurred while finding the resource dictionary "pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml".**

Please see image for the code snippet.
[Error Encountered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AOnq.png)

I already search it but i can't find the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Is 'Controls.xaml' in the spot where it's supposed to be?

Comment: Yes, based on documentation of MahApps, it was placed inside the Resources.MergedDictionaries. I already try to reinstall it but still same error occured.

Comment: I already solved it by changing the framework from 4.6 to 4.7.1. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.